# Quit option in Gnome Fileroller

Tags: gnome, file-roller

Every time I extracted a file from fileroller it shows me three options:

Quit - Close - Show files

But I upgrade the fileroller this time I have only two options:

Close and Show files

[image: Fileroller New]

I'm looking for missing option but it's gone, how can I put it back again?

Comment: downgrade fileroller to version you used before updating, or wait for next version, or not (it could be their strategy to remove that button! typical gnome developers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Paolo's email the developer of fileroller the quit option removed from code since version 3.20.